# Docker(docker-compose) node + MySQL: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file, that is running three containers. My problem is when I start my containers it seems like my node(api) container is starting before my MySQL container, even if I declare depends_on on my docker-compose.yml, giving me the following error:

```
error connecting: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xx.x.x:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
```

After I got this error I can see in my console that the MySQL container is just starting. My database is ok, I can access it without any problems. If I make some change in my nodejs code, then this will make my node server to refresh and when the server is up again I don't have any connections problems, because the MySQL container is already up.

I even tried to use solutions as wait-for-it.sh (https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh), but the result was the same, my node backend tries to make a mysql connection, but the mysql container is not ready.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: my_mysql
        build: ./db
        restart: always
        container_name: my_mysql
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mysql
            - ./db:/db
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=x 
            - MYSQL_USER=x
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=x
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=x
        networks: 
            - my_network
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    api:
        container_name: my_api
        build: ./api
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        environment:
            DB_HOSTNAME: mysql    
        working_dir: /api
        volumes:
            - ./api:/api
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        networks:
            - my_network
    client:
        container_name: my_client
        image: mhart/alpine-node:12
        build: ./client
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        working_dir: /client
        volumes:
            - ./client:/client
        entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]
        depends_on: 
            - api
        networks: 
            - my_network
networks:
    my_network:
        driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for my nodejs backend:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12
WORKDIR /api
COPY package*.json /api/
RUN npm i -G nodemon
RUN npm install
COPY . /api/
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Dockerfile for my react front:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12
WORKDIR /client
COPY package*.json /client/
RUN npm install
COPY . /client/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and Dockerfile for mysql:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.19
```

Calling mysql connection in nodejs:

```
const config = require('config');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : config.get('mysql.config.host'),
  user     : config.get('mysql.config.user'),
  password : config.get('mysql.config.password'),
  database : config.get('mysql.config.database'),
  port     : config.get('mysql.config.port')
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected  as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

  connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    res.send(`MySQL OK: ${results[0].solution}`);
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I could not test it, but the docker recommendation is to create a script to wait until the other container accepts connections.

> Alternatively, write your own wrapper script to perform a more application-specific health check. For example, you might want to wait until Postgres is definitely ready to accept commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

You could check the documentation here:
[Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Hope this helps.